# How to draw scrollbar at particular position in a surfaceview in android

Tags: android, canvas, scrollbar

I am taking a surfaceview in xml file and drawing text,rectangle on the surfaceview by overriding ondraw() method and I want to make some part as a scrollable at surfaceview.

for reference--
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ycYp356qrno

in this app one page where all task are display and progress status is scrollable

pls help...